# Whitespace is being added to an overlay in IE9, but not in Fx5

Tags: css, html, overlay, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to overlay a "search box" over a Google Maps API V3. The overlay works fine in Fx5, but in IE9 it does not work quite right. Some white space is added by IE9 between the map and the gray `div`. To see the difference, go to:

http://www.trailheadfinder.com/trail_search/trail_map

The "search box" should be aligned with the `Map`/`Sattelite`/`MyTopo` buttons.

### HTML

```
<div id="maplayers">
 Select information to be shown:
 Trails: <input type="checkbox" id="trailsbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'trails')" />
 Campgrounds: <input type="checkbox" id="campgroundsbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'campgrounds')" />
 Panoramio: <input type="checkbox" id="panoramiobox" />
</div>
<div>
 <div id="mapsearchbar">
  <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
 </div>
 <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
#mapsearchbar {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 right: 200px;
 top: 5px;
 z-index: 999;
}
#maplayers {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-color: #C4C4C4;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap is there because you are giving it a position of relative and then offsetting is using top: 5px; right: 200px. This cause it to move but leave a gap in its origional position. Do as follows.

```
div
{
position: relative;
}

div#mapserachbar
{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
right: 170px;
}
```

And remove float:right from it.

Comment: By the way. In FF5 you have the same problem.

Comment: Offcourse div refers to the the div right under the div#maplayers. Since you are not naming your div either using an id or class, the above code will be applied to all the divs. To correct that, use either an id or class and then style it.

Comment: Thanks guys. That did the trick. I had to keep the z-index at 999 to make sure it stays on top of the map. For some reason my FF5 on Mac and Win7 didn't show the problem.

Comment: @user823567: Hmmmmmmmmmm. Well on windows, IE9 showed the same problem. Glad you sorted it out. Good luck.